# What's a canonical example of code kata to learn about pointers?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

I've never worked with a language that didn't provide for some form of memory management, and thus managed to get by without ever really groking pointers.

I can dabble in `C` I guess, as a result of coding in `Objective-C` for a little while.

Comment: Here is a question you might enjoy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695373/pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-memory-block-will-not-deallocate-for-some he he :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, maybe it's the single linked list.

Try it: **create, populate, reverse, release** a single linked list

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: And then graduating to double-linked lists and binary trees, I would say.

Comment: I had hoped for more answers, but this is a good one nonetheless !

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this "canonical", but I'm recreating `[arrayOfStrings sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];` using `char *` arrays and pure C code. It's sloppy and frustrating, but great practice and I'm loving it.

http://github.com/jkubicek/Objective-Sort/blob/master/Objective-Sort.m

Answer (score 0):

I've started a small github project to collect objective-c katas: https://github.com/twobitlabs/xcode-katas